# What is the simplest way to do simple distributed communication in .NET?

Tags: c#, sql-server, msmq

So basically I am thinking about attempting load testing on my asp.net application using various features all at once.  There is a lot of dependencies and ajax requests being performed in this application so it seems like a simple replay of captured http requests will not suffice and due to other features like picking out random operations, performing then verifying results across several machines, simple load testing software will not suffice.

Also there is no budget to this project for spending, so commercial implementations can not be used.  I'm debating on trying to use MSMQ (never used before) to handle communication between clients, but if that is really complicated to set up then I would either use a database table as a queue or a simple TCP server with each test machine as its clients.

Features I want are: immediate failure (one client crashes, then all clients should stop), each test run should start with a brand new scenario with no prior messages, and ability to publish a start and stop event.  Also it would be nice if I don't have to worry about state management (leaning towards TCP server for this over database) or concurrency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't sound like MSMQ is what you need. It is a message-passing asynchronous communication method, akin to email. You can send a message to another queue that no one is even listening to (i.e. the application isn't running). It seems to me you want a more "online" communication model.

How about creating agents (client applications that sit on many machines and create the load) that expose a WCF service where a controller program can connect to all of them and instruct the agents what to do? It can be a duplex contract, so that the agents can send the controller a notifications. When one of them send a error notification, the controller can instruct all the other agents to shut down. Also I'd go for a Net.TCP binding rather than HTTP binding.